# Jquery serialize and php insert to database

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a form with a few rows that I am trying to insert the values into the database. I am using jquery serialize to send the ajax post to the page. At this point, I am lost for how to send the values properly in an array so I can get the values. There are approx 10 rows with the same input id's. Quantity, Price, Part Number. I send all ten to the php page. I need to retreive these ten rows and insert.  Any help is appreciated. Here is the code.

```
<form id="form">
////These row repeat. Total of 10 
<input name="PartQuantity[]" type="text"  id="PartQuantity" size="2" /> 
<select name="PartType[]"  id="PartType">
<input name="PartNumber[]" type="text"  id="PartNumber" size="10" />
</form>
```

jquery

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.showResults').live('click', function() {

var post = $('#form').serialize(); 
jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax/page_activity/forms/insert_parts.php",
        data: post,
        cache: false,
        success: function(html)
            {

            alert(html)

                }
        });
 });

 });
 </script>
```

php page

```
 <?php 
 $quantity_array = $_POST['PartQuantity'];
 foreach ($quantity_array as $quantity)
 {
 ///insert values
 }
 ?>
```

I can only print out the values for one of these arrays, not all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$query = '';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_POST['PartQuantity']);$i++){
  $query .= "(".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PartQuantity'][$i]).",".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PartType'][$i]).",".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['PartNumber'][$i])."),";
}
$query = substr($query,0,strlen($query) - 1); //STRIP LAST COMMA
$result = mysql_query("insert into <TABLE> (partquantity,parttype,partnumber) VALUES $query") or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: sql injection is apparently a thing to avoid

Comment: well, it's kinda hard to answer this question. would "just visiting" suit you?

Comment: The downvote is for posting the code which is widely open to the most notorious attack.

Comment: this correction did nothing good. it is still as vulnerable as it was at first.

Comment: For some reason this only entered in one row when there are 10 rows. I changed the count => POST[PartQuantity] to PartType and it worked. Just for my knowledge, why would a text string work and a number not work for counting the rows?

Comment: btw Buck thanks for the response and the help. I did modify the code to prevent injection, just so no one has a heart attack. And up voted you.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is fine on your code.

If you can´t grab the values correctly, consider typos, including in your answer, real data, real errors or putting more debugging information, jquery version etc. like the print_r($_POST) below:

```
Array
(
    [PartQuantity] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

    [PartType] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 1
        )

    [PartNumber] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer...I can print these arrays just like you have them above. Where I an stuck is how to insert these values into the database. For example row 1 PartQuantity: 1, PartNumber: xxx, PartType: 3...Next row PartQuantity: 2, PartNumber: xyz, PartType: 4...an so on. I can only insert just one of the arrays, like the partNumber. But I need all the values in the row.

Comment: If you can print that array, then loop thru it and make a query accordingly.